# Angular 6 ActivatedRoute url

Tags: angular

Here I have MyComponent in which router loads different other components depending on route, I want to get full current route in header component, but ActivatedRoute.url is showing only {path: "d"} not the full path, or the last part of path(which I need). 
Do you have any ideas on how can I get in header component the loaded route.

**my-component.component.html**

```
<app-header></app-header>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

**header.component.ts**

```
 ...
constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {}
ngOnInit() {
    this.route.url.subscribe(url=>console.log(url));
}
```

**my-module-routing.module.ts**

```
    {
    path: 'd',
    component: MyComponent,
    children: [
        {
            path: 'discover',
            component: DiscoverComponent
        },
        {
            path: 'book/:id',
            component: BookPageComponent
        },
        {
            path: 'search',
            component: SearchPageComponent
        }]
    }
```

---

when on d/search console.logs

```
[UrlSegment]
0: UrlSegment
parameterMap: ParamsAsMap
parameters: {}
path: "d"
__proto__: Object
length: 1
__proto__: Array(0)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can simply use this technique

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
    import {ActivatedRoute} from "@angular/router";
    @Component({
      selector: 'app-header',
      templateUrl: './header.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./header.component.scss']
    })
    export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {
      constructor(private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) {
        this.activatedRoute.url.subscribe(activeUrl =>{
          this.url=window.location.pathname;
        });
      }

      ngOnInit() {
      }

    }
```

Comment: @YashaGasparyan as a side note, the activated route is on the current route : if you have deep routes (e.g. `path/to/deep/route`) and you use your `ActivatedRoute` in the component of `/path/`, you won't get the rest of the route.

Answer (score 1):

You can access first child data by:

```
constructor(route: ActivatedRoute) {
  route.url.subscribe(() => {
    console.log(route.snapshot.firstChild.data);
   });
}
```

Comment: I tried that. The problem is snapshot isn't observable, and I can't get information about route being changed.

Answer (score 0):

That's because the URL is a string that is constructed on navigation events.

I suggest you listen to navigation events, then map the result to the current URL.

[This stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-router-basic-example-hcsbbm?file=app/app.component.ts) explains how to do that.

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
  <div class="container">
    <a routerLinkActive="active" 
      routerLink="/login">Login</a> |

    <a routerLinkActive="active" 
      routerLink="/home">Home</a> | 

    <a routerLinkActive="active" 
      routerLink="/catalog">Catalog</a> 

    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  </div>
  <div>
    Current route : {{ url$ | async }}
  </div>
  `,
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {

  url$ = this.router.events.pipe(
    map(() => this.router.url),
  );

  constructor(
    private router: Router
  ) {}

}
```

Comment: I tried to use router events. This does not work when you go to url directly from browser.

Comment: It works in my stackblitz. If it doesn't in your project, then please provide a [mcve].

Comment: I can't figure out why this didn't work in my project when going to url from browser, although it works when using routing in app. Anyway this is a good example and it can be useful in other cases. Thank you.